# How to disable button Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I have a button with id of `btnAdd` and I want to disable it when some event is fired. The event occurs when some window is closed. So I tried the following code and it does not work.

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    // Some initialization code goes here...
    listeners: {
       close: function(panel, eOpts){
          Ext.get('btnAdd').disable(); // this does not work;
          Ext.get('btnAdd').setDisabled(); // this one does not either
          Ext.get('btnAdd').disabled = true; // And this one also seems to do nothing
       }
    }
});
```

How can I do that? This may seem to be pretty easy question but don't judge me bad. I'm quite new to Ext JS. I could not find the answer in the API Documentation either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Ext.get('btnAdd').setDisabled(true);
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-method-setDisabled

Comment: You solution was true, but I had to change one thing. Instead of Ext.get() I had to use Ext.getCmp(). So Ext.getCmp('btnAdd').setDisabled(true); this one worked perfectly. And can you tell me what is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: @Dima: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-get & http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp

Answer (score 4):

IF the button is Extjs component then use

```
Ext.getCmp('btnAdd').disable();
```

If it is not Ext js Component then use

```
Ext.get('btnAdd').setDisabled(true);
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

```
Ext.get('btnid').disable();
Ext.get('btnid').setDisabled(true);
```

both return errors, the best way that work without issues is

```
Ext.getCmp('btnid').setDisabled(true)
```

and you can set a text when the button is disabled to notify the user.

Example:

```
Ext.getCmp('btnid').setText("Button has been disabled")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.get('btnid').disable();
Ext.get('btnid').setDisabled(true);
```