# How I can call ext.net button from Javascript and set to enable it?

Tags: javascript, ext.net

```
var btnNextp = Ext.getCmp('<% = btnNextPage.ClientID %>').getEl().dom.id;
//var  btnNextp = document.getElementById('<% = btnNextPage.ClientID %>');

// $("#btnNextPage").attr({ disabled: "false" }); 
Ext.getCmp('btnNextp').setBtnDisable(false); //not works properly
// Ext.getCmp('btnNextPage').enable();   //not works properly
```

These examples also creates uncaught errors in javascript.But why ?where is the problems.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps look at this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314166/how-to-disable-button-ext-js/33228452#33228452

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var EnableButton = function () {
        var btnNextp = #{btnNextPage};
            btnNextp.setDisabled(false);
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefano Lonati

Comment: @OyaliulIslam :) Accept the response please